# How to Show and Edit HTML in iOS?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, uitextview

I have a PM-system in my homepage and now building a app for this.

I want to show this PM now and in the next view edit it.

Showing is very simple, because I can use UIWebView for this.
But how to have and editable UIWebView, something like a RichtTextBox in iOS for this?

My only idea was to cut the HTML complete away from the PM an then display and edit in UITextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your system provide any kind of webservice interface (like REST or SOAP)? If you want to build the PM system as a native iOS App you should forget about the uiwebview and build the user interface yourself. Get the data remotely from your PM system (as XML, JSON, whatever), parse it and update the ui elements. That way you can layout and manage your ui and data as you wish.

Edit: If it doesn't maybe you should make the views of you web app iPhone compatible (e.g. sencha touch, jquery mobile) and try e.g. Phonegap.